# git restore a deleted file after merge

Tags: git

I  am trying to recover a file that was accidentally removed when I merged a branch to the master.

Now, when I try to do a git checkout of a new branch I get this message:

```
 $ git checkout testingNewFormStyle
D       module/FormDependencies/src/FormDependencies/Entity/LanguageList.php
Switched to branch 'testingNewFormStyle'
```

However, I want to restore that file. How can I do this?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can do, for instance:

```
git checkout HEAD -- module/FormDependencies/src/FormDependencies/Entity/LanguageList.php
```

This will checkout the file as it exists in the HEAD refspec (ie, the current branch). If HEAD is not what you want, replace with the appropriate refspec.