# File deletion after wrong merge

Tags: git, git-merge

We have two  branches in  GIT. Master (M1)  and   Release (R1).

M1 is periodically merged into R1.

Someone  accidentally  merged R1 into M1. The  merge was reverted back.
Check-ins continued in  M1 and also in R1.

Now  when I   try to merge M1 into R1 ,   GIT is asking to delete  140 files from R1.
I don't want those files to be deleted.

How can I merge M1  into R1  without deleting the files in  R1?

I can use  GIT status,  save those 140 files  somewhere, let the merge  delete those  140  files, copy the saved files again and commit.
But I am hoping there may be a simpler way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But I am hoping there may be a simpler way to do it

That might actually be the more straight-forward workaround, to allow you to move forward.
The idea is to allow the merge to proceed for common files, while beeing able to restore deleted files.

As an alternative, You can also try a [merge without auto-commit](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8640887/6309), and [restore the deleted files](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21698907/6309) (with a `git checkout sourceBranch -- adeletedFile`) before committing (which completes the merge)